# How to get object in Angular5?

Tags: angular

I have a problem with getting an Array in Angular. It only works if I click  the button twice to get the Array. I need to get the data in 1 click (see Img at the end of the page).

```
@Injectable()
export class ConexionPersonService {

_people: Person[];

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
) { }

public getPeople(): void {

    const url = 'assets/Json/listPerson.json'; 
    this.http.get<Person[]>(url).subscribe(data => {this._people = data});
    console.log('ANTESobtenido ' , this._people);
}

public getPerson(id:number): Person{

    console.log('ID ' , id);

    if(this._people) {
        var per = this._people.find(person => person.id_user == id);
        console.log('obtenido ' , per);
        return this._people.find(person => person.id_user == id);
    }
}


}
```

---

```
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit {

    detailPerson: Person;
    People:Person[];
    @Input() id;
    that;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private conexion: ConexionPersonService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.conexion.getPeople();
        this.getPerson();
    }


    getPerson(): void {

        this.detailPerson = this.conexion.getPerson(this.id);   

     }
```

So the problem is that the first time it does not work, but after that it does work.

[image: Img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation is not correct, it could be more simpler have a look on following solution:

**service**

```
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit { 
    detailPerson: Person;
    @Input() id;

    constructor(private service: ConexionPersonService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.getPerson();
    }

    getPerson(): void {  
        this.detailPerson = this.conexion.getPerson(this.id);      
    } 
}
```

**service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConexionPersonService {
    _people: Person[];

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) { 
        this.getPeople();
    }

    public getPeople() {

        const url = 'assets/Json/listPerson.json';
        this.http.get<Person[]>(url).subscribe(data => this._people = data);
    }

    public getPerson(id:number): Person {

        if(this._people) {
            return this._people.find(person => person.id_user = id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need return in getPeople because It is call the detailUserComponent or  I use Observable need Return

Comment: I need get Array the People for search 1 user for 'id_user' but I don't know to access the array People.

Comment: I update the question.ty  Anshuman Jaiswal. I need press the button twice for get data....

Comment: constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
  getPeople,
 ) { } ???????? Can you more specific, pls ?

Comment: no just check the updated answer, I have already called `this.getPeople()` in constructor.

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry.  with 1 click : 
ANTESobtenido  undefined
ANTESobtenido  undefined
more click yes

Comment: can you try by calling `this.getPerson();` in `ngAfterViewInit()` rather than in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: I think that is because I don't use Observable<Person[]> in public getPeople(): I need return with Observable, but I don't  nothing return in public getPeople(): Observable<Person[]>

Comment: You don't call getPeople in ConexionPersonService

Comment: it's there in service itself as soon as object of service is created, it will call `getPeople()`

Comment: Okay, can you create a stackblitz/plunker with your code. it would be easier to debug the problem.

Comment: Finally , I got resolve this problem, very thanks. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154855/no-carga-los-datos-la-primera-vez-en-angular5/154901#154901

Answer (score 0):

By the time you retrieve the list of people (async), the code to get a specific person has already been executed and returning null.

So.. Either you update the code for specific person in the subscribe handler of people list or let the people retrieval happen on ngOnInit and person retrieval to happen on button click or ngAfterViewInit().

Ideally the people list retrieval should happen in service's own initialization (better) or the specific person search can be done via chaining the two requests directly (get people list from http and in success handler, search for the id); although it will repeat the http call (hence not so desired).